# php using eval to obtain an objects attribute value

Tags: php

I am trying to set a function that will dynamically update an object attribute in the db w/o updating the whole object.

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . self::$table_name . " SET ";
$sql .= "$attribute = '" . eval("\$this->$attribute;") . "'";
$sql .= " WHERE ...";
```

I cant seem to get this  *eval("\$this->$attribute;")* to produce the object attribute value. There is a value in the attribute and it is a public attribute.

Thanks

$attribute is a function var that will contain a string like 'address_id' so I want
     UPDATE table_name SET address_id = '11' WHERE user_id='1' 
This is a simple example of it

Comment: Why do you need to `eval()` it? Surely `$this->attribute` will suffice?

Comment: <cringe /> Why do you need to use eval in the first place? Why not simply use $this->attribute?

Comment: And learn to use Prepared statements

Comment: almost any time you use `eval()`, you're making a mistake. `eval()` is almost always unnecessary. It certainly doesn't seem necessary here.

Comment: $attribute is a function variable, tried '$this->attribute' didnt work. however I tried '$sql .= eval("return \$this->" . $attribute . ";");' and it worked.

Comment: You don't need `eval()` at all here...

Comment: .. as in function updateAttribute($attribute) {......} it is a generic  function that I can use as the class is inherited for very specific updates

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this using eval. PHP supports variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

So this will do:

```
$this->$attributes
```

Note the second `$` sign. This basicly means the value of $attributes is used as attribute name. If you want it to write a bit clearer you can do so using brackets:

```
$this->{$attributes}
```

This bracket is required if you wanted to do this using an array, or if you wanted to use multiple variables to build a variable name like this:

```
$this->{$var1}_{$array[0]}_{$var2}
```

This goes probably behind the scope of this question, but its good to know what variable variables are. But i don't recommend using them, because it makes the code unreadable and hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `eval()`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . self::$table_name . " SET ";
$sql .= "$attribute = '" . $this->attribute . "'";
$sql .= " WHERE ...";
```

If `attribute` is a variable, use:

```
$this->$attribute
```

Are you sure `$this->attribute` is sanitized correctly?

Comment: I think it should be like this 
`'".$this->attribute."'`

Comment: Not if it's a variable variable.

Comment: you forgot the first dot `.` for the concatination

Comment: Then the above should be fine.

Comment: @BasicBridge BenM didn't get the concatination issue, i did, so i wrote it again so he understands what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. My bad.

Comment: Thanks! Still new at PHP so learning some tricks....  $sql .= "$attribute = '" . $this->$attribute . "'"; worked